# What is the most effecient way to start this application?

Tags: linux, symlink, path

I installed BurpSuiteCommunity and the executable went to `/opt` folder, so I moved it to /usr/bin because `/usr/bin` is part of my PATH and most of applications were already there.  I tried to do run `BurpSuiteCommunity` in my home folder but it could not find the command.  Then I found that the application is actually in `/usr/bin/BurpSuiteCommunity/BurpSuiteCommunity`.  If I were to go into that directory and run `BurpSuiteCommunity` the application would run.

I tried to make a symlink in `/usr/local/bin` (which is in my PATH) that points to BSC.  If I try to go back to my home folder and type `burp` I get a message which says

```
zsh: no such file or directory: ./usr/bin/BurpSuiteCommunity/BurpSuiteCommunity
```

How can I type `burp` anywhere and run my application?

SOLUTION EDIT:

This is what I did to fix the problem:

1. I moved BSC back to /opt as suggested by mikem.
2. I modified by .zshrc by adding this export statement:

   `export PATH=/opt/BurpSuiteCommunity/:$PATH`
3. I then modified by .zshrc again by adding this alias:

   `alias burp="BurpSuiteCommunity"`
4. Then I typed `zsh` to restart the shell. Resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you moved the entire burpsuite into /usr/bin -- as if you did:

```
mv /opt/BurpSuiteCommunity /usr/bin
```

Really you just want to add the burpsuite bin directory to your path while leaving burpsuite in it's normal location.

Move burpsuite back to /opt

```
# mv /usr/bin/BurpSuiteCommunity /opt
```

Then edit the PATH variable in your $HOME/.bash_profile

```
PATH=$PATH:/opt/BurpSuiteCommunity/bin
```

Save the .bash_profile and once you're back at your shell, source it:

```
$ . ./.bash_profile
```

Once it's in your $PATH, you can execute it from anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

1. How did you do the symlink? It looks like

   ```
   ln -s /opt/BurpSuiteCommunity /usr/bin
   ```

   Like this you symlink the folder, you'll likely only need the executable, so try

   ```
   ln -s /opt/BurpSuiteCommunity/BurpSuiteCommunity /usr/bin
   ```
2. For some reason your symlink points to

   ```
   ./usr/bin/BurpSuiteCommunity/BurpSuiteCommunity
   ```

   instead of

   ```
   /usr/bin/BurpSuiteCommunity/BurpSuiteCommunity
   ```

   Note the `.` Your symlink will look for `/usr/bin/BurpSuiteCommunity/BurpSuiteCommunity` in the directory the symlink sits (i.e. `/usr/bin`).